# bootstrap validator not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="validator/src/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
<div class="row-fluid">
  <!--<div class="span6 offset3">-->
    <div class="well" style="margin:0 auto;max-width:500px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px gray; background-color: #F7F7FA">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;color:#0072a7; font-family: Times new roman"><strong>REGISTRATION FORM</strong></h1>
    <hr style="height:1px; background-color: #0072a7;">
  </div>
```

Name: *

```
            <tr style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <td><div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label;">Email Id:</label><span style="color:red"> *</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span><input type="email" size="100;" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
          </div></td>
        </tr>


        <tr style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <td><div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label;">Contact:</label><span style="color:red"> *</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone form-control-feedback"></span><input type="text" size= "100;" name="contact" class="form-control" id="contact" placeholder="Enter your contact number">
          </div></td>
        </tr>


        <tr style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <td><label class="control-label">Course:</label><span style="color:red"> *</span>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" value="CSE" name="course" style="width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;CSE&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <label><input type="radio" value="IT" name="course" style="width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;IT&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <label><input type="radio" value="ECE" name="course" style="width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;ECE&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <label><input type="radio" value="EEE" name="course" style="width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;EEE&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


        <tr style="padding-top: 10px;">
          <td><label class="control-label">Year:</label><span style="color:red"> *</span>
            <div class="radio">
              <label><input type="radio" name="year" style="width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;First Year&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <label><input type="radio" name="year" style="width:15px;height:15px; padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;Second Year&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <label><input type="radio" name="year" style="width:15px;height:15px;padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;Third Year&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <label><input type="radio" name="year" style="width:15px;height:15px; padding-bottom:2px;">&nbsp;Fourth Year&nbsp;</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </div>
        </tr>

     <tr style="padding-top: 15px;">
          <td><label class="control-label">Are you a Robot?</label><span style="color:red"> *</span>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" style="width:15px; height:15px;" name="robot" />Yes</label>&nbsp;
            <label><input type="checkbox" style="width:15px; height:15px;" name="robot" />No</label>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>









        <tr style="padding-top: 15px;">
          <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right"><td>
        </tr>

      </table>
    </form>
  <!--</div>-->

   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#registration').bootstrapValidator({
       message: 'This value is not valid',
       feedbackIcons: {
         valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
         invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
         validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
      },
      fields: {
        name: {
          validators: {
            notEmpty: {
              message: 'The full name is required and cannot be empty'
       },
       regexp: {
         regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+$/,
         message: 'The name can only consist of alphabets'
       }
      }
    },
     email: {
       validators:{
         notEmpty:{
           message:'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
       },
       emailAddress: {
                    message: 'The email address is not valid'
                }
     }
    }
  },

  contact: {
   message: 'The mobile mumber is not valid',
     validators: {
       notEmpty:{
         message: 'The Mobile Number is required and cannot be empty'
     },
     stringLength:{
       min: 10,
       max: 10,
       message: 'Please enter a valid Mobile Number.'
   },
  regexp:{
    regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
      message: 'The Mobile Number can only consist of numerical values'
    },
  }
},
    course: {
      validators:{ 
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'The branch is required'
     }
   }
 },
     year: {
       validators:{
          notEmpty:{
            message: 'The year is required'
        }
     }
},
robot: {
    validators: {
      notEmpty: {
        message: 'Select either yes or no'
    }
  } 
}
},
.on('success.form.bv', function(e){

  var $form = $(e.target);
  var bv = $form.data('bootstrapValidator');

  $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(result){
     console.log(result);
}, 'json');


});
});

</script>
</div>
</div>











































    </body>
    </html>
```

bootstrap validator in the given code does not work at all, could anyone point out the errors ? Is there any problem with the cdn? submitting the form is a bit tricky. also could anyone explain the ajax coding ?

Comment: did you separate that html intentionally?

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389767/how-do-i-execute-a-php-query-on-select-option-choice-using-ajax/32389802#32389802 check this link there is an answer for ajax. it can help

Comment: What have you tried to fix the problem? You should cut down your code to the smallest possible amout that still reproduces the problem. Also split your multiple questions into separate questions as that will improve your chances of getting good answers.