# AJAX + css page transitions

Tags: jquery, ajax

Could someone explain AJAX page transitions in a step by step process? I have seen many explains but I can't seem to find one that explains it step by step.
I can't seem to grasp the concept. Something like the following code perhaps? Or even anything simpler will work too.

Basically, I want to display a new page when I click on my navigation menu link without the page having to reload. And possibly add animations to that.

Also, what is the significance of adding the "error" call and is it compulsory?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#pages-load-area #pages-container").load("./pages/" + initialPage);

    $("#header-navigation a").on("click", function() {

        var urlPageName = $(this).attr("href");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "./pages/" + urlPageName,
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result, responseData) {
                $("#pages-load-area    #pages-container").html(result);
            },
            error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('AJAX failed');
            },
        });

        return false;

    });
});
```

Comment: Also, what is the implication of "return false" ?

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation on how to solve while better understanding the solution for ajax content calls/updates on single page app?  Or, are you asking how jQuery ajax can be applied webapp like page functionality within your own personal site?

Comment: Just the functions inside the ajax array as in- "type" "url", "processData" .... upto "error".
What are these functions doing? And is this a standard format for ajax, that will not work with out all the parameters in place?

Comment: you are missing the `dataType: "json",` the type of data that will be the response from the `url` also you dont have the `data:`  the data that you will be passing to the `url`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389767/how-do-i-execute-a-php-query-on-select-option-choice-using-ajax/32389802#32389802 see my answer here i hope it can help you

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253687/java-script-auto-refresh-update-function-but-getting-one-error/32253932#32253932), although basic, might help a bit -- especially the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX doesn't do "page transitions". It does an asynchronous call to the server and runs a return function or an error function. 
The return function has a parameter where the server can send some data to the client. With that data you can do whatever you want to do.

If the server sends the next page and you get that result and you substitute some of the html by the result, you can use this functionality to do "page transitions". But it's very important to keep the concepts separate in order for you to understand what's going on.

So if you send an ajax request like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./pages/sum",
        data: {
            a: 3,
            b: 4
        },
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('AJAX failed');
        },
    });
```

and the server responds with '7'. Then your alert will display 7. The variables present in 'data' will be available from the GET scope in your server. I don't know which server laguage you are using. In PHP that would be in $_GET.

Example of a PHP page that would return '7':

```
<?php
    return $_GET['a'] + $_GET['b'];
?>
```

Another example:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./pages/sum",
        data: {
            a: 3,
            b: 4
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $("input#result").text(result);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('AJAX failed');
        },
    });
```

now once the call returns your input named "result" will display '7' inside of it.

Now back to your case, you can do as `url: "./pages/" + urlPageName,` but you can also use:
:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./pages",
        data: {
            pageName: urlPageName
        },
        success: function(result, responseData) {
            $("#pages-load-area    #pages-container").html(result);
        },
        error: function(responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('AJAX failed');
        },
    });
```

Depending on what server technology you're using this may make your life easier. So in this case you're simply replacing the html inside "#pages-load-area    #pages-container" element by whatever the server returns to you.

One more thing, at this point you don't need:

```
processData: false,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
```

forget about them for now and go back at them when you have your mind more clear about ajax calls.

About the "return false", if you read [this](http://api.jquery.com/on/) page from jQuery documentation, you may notice this relevant part:

> Returning false from an event handler will automatically call
>   event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault()"

That means that if you have say, a button inside a div and you set an onclick event for the button with the event's function ending with `return false` and an onclick event for the div, when you click the button the div's onclick event will not be fired because of that false. So you will have only one onclick event.

I hope I have clarified. Feel free to ask more if it's not clear yet.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. The only part I didn't understand is, in your first two examples, you are implying that if you feed "data- a=3, b=4" and send an Ajax call, the output will be 7. So you are saying the result function is defined as "a+b" or "3+4". But I can't see where you defined that though.

Comment: You're welcome. I can also see you're new here, so if you think my answer was helpful you can upvote it. If you think it solved your problem or was the best answer given, you can accept it (I mean clicking the checkmark below up/down votes button. :) Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: No I'm not saying the result will be 7. What I said was, that if you provide the server with a=3, b=4 AND the server return 7 THEN your alert will display 7. The way how the server sent that 7 is not shown. I could have made a server example, but you didn't said what server side language you're using, so I could give an example in a language you didn't understand.

Comment: I included a small php server example that would return 7.