# Why does this ajax not work?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32390447/7932947

I am trying to do a query through the database when someone press on the table row with the said user so I can display the information for him.

Here is my code:

ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rowID").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var idt = "id="+id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get-data.php",
            data: ids,
            success: function(result){
                $("#userBox").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<tr data-id="<?php echo $datum['ID']; ?>" id="rowID" href="#">
```

get-data.php:

```
<?php
include("../connect.php");
session_start();

  if(!empty($_POST["id"])){
    echo "test";
  }

?>
```

And it is not working, not sure why.., I don't see any "Test" displayed inside the userBox

Comment: You have no `ids` variable, I presume it's a typo and you meant `idt`. Also be very careful of having duplicate `id` attributes. Your use of an `id` on the `tr` implies that you need to use classes instead

Comment: check your `data` in your ajax, it should be like this `data {'id': idt}`

Comment: Oh.. it was a typo.. sorry for wasting your time guys.. :(
Also @RoryMcCrossan can you explain me what you mean with the id on tr and classes? Didn't really understand :s

Comment: I mean that you shouldn't have more than one element with this attribute: `id="rowID"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the below code form ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType:"application\json;charset=utf-8",
    url: "get-data.php",
    data: {id:id},
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(result){
        $("#userBox").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why {id:id} instead of 
`idt = "id="+id` then `data: idt,` also if I use your version, I can remove the idt var?

Comment: yes , no need idt variable here.also in ajax call when you pass parameter then the format i have set is proper format.