# Dynamic Select Box Dependent Using MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

I'm developing a website for comparing prices of cars:

The user should enter:
Year
Make
Model

Database Structre & Example:

id -- year -- make -- model

1     2018    Fiat    Ponto

2     2018    Seat    Leon

3     2017    Hyundai Veloster

So Now I'm displaying Select boxes but I need it to get the Select Box Value Before submitting form.

```html
              <div>
                <?php
                     $cars = "SELECT distinct year FROM `cars` ";
                      $carsResult = mysqli_query($conn, $cars);
                 ?>
              <select name="year" class="selectStyle">
                   <option disabled selected >Year</option>
                    <?php
                           if(mysqli_num_rows($carsResult) > 0){
                         while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($carsResult)){
                                                              ?>
                 <option id="year" value="<?php echo $row['year']; ?>"><?php echo $row['year']; ?></option>

                                                              <?php
                                                          }
                                                      } else {
                                                          ?>
                                                              <option       value="">0 results</option>
                                                          <?php
                                                      }
                                                      ?>
                                  </select>


                <


          <select name="make" class="selectStyle">
          <option disabled selected>Make</option>
          // Here I need to display more

          </select>


              </div>
```

So on the second Select I need to display only for the selected year:
"SELECT make FROM cars WHERE year = {users year}"
How can i get the user selected year to the sql query?

So after i can check:
"SELECT model From cars WHERE year= {users year} AND model = {users model}"

Please help me, I'm tring forever now!

Comment: You will need to use AJAX to call a php script on your server that returns the list for the next *<SELECT>* object. When the data is returned from the ajax call, you use that data to populate the options for the next select.

Comment: Can you help me with snippet please? i'm stuck for days now

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389767/how-do-i-execute-a-php-query-on-select-option-choice-using-ajax) should get you started. The first answer has a good, simple example.

Comment: You're the best. finally got it to work! Thank you!