# Create SQL Query with <options> tag and echo result?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I want to set up a page where you can see how much it will cost to repair your broken mobile phone. I have a database with all the issues, phones and prices. Now I want to print the price after the user seletected a phone and the issue.

So this is my question: How do I now get the selection the user has done and use it in php to create the correct sql query in order to echo the price?

Database (Numbers are the price):

| issue | iphone_8 | iphone_xs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| battery | 25 | 50 |
| waterdamage | 60 | 100 |

Design:

[This is how it is supposed to look like. So you can better understand what I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4di8.png)

HTML:

Currently looks like this:

```
<select>
    <option>Select device</option>
    <option>iPhone 8</option>
    <option>iPhone XS</option>
</select>
<select>
    <option>Select issue</option>
    <option>Battery</option>
    <option>Water Damage</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

Selecting data works fine. I am using the default w3c layout to select data with php out of my database: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: `How do I now get the selection the user has done`...this is something which occurs naturally when the user submits the form. Or you can have it be triggerred by another event on the page (e.g. user changing the selection) and send the request via AJAX to return the price. Up to you really. I'm guessing you haven't studied forms yet?

Comment: P.S. `I am using the default w3c layout` I think you may have got confused between [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) and [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/). They are _very_ different organisations! w3schools is usually a poor resource btw, not ideal to learn from.

Comment: Hey @ADyson thanks for your answer. No I do not know much about forms. I think I have to add a submit button. But how will I let php know what the user has submitted and how do I work with it. Do you have any guides I can look into?

Comment: `how will I let php know what the user has submitted`...that's the browser's job. You create the form, the fields, and the submit button. The browser will send the entered data to the server when the form is submitted. PHP will be able to read that data through some special variables it creates. You really need to take some introductory tutorials, there are plenty available online covering HTML forms and PHP. We don't provide tutorials (or recommendations for them) on Stackoverflow, but you can search easily.

Comment: However the PHP manual has a really simple example to get you started: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Wrap the <select> with form tag and submit the form with OnChange event(). This way you can get the $_POST value of device & issue, then make query to get price value. Finally echo the price value to the price label.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding **OnChange** event() on `<select>` tag, and **submit() the form**. Next do the **query**, get the price and **update** your price value.

This is a **sample code**:

1. **PHP Code**

```
//If phone and screen both selected
if (!empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['issue']) ){

    /* DO YOUR QUERY */

    $price = ...;

}
```

What this **sample code** do: As soon as the form is submitted, it will go through the PHP from top of the page, check if both "phone" and "issue"  are **selected**, if yes, do PHP Query and get resulting **price**.

2. **HTML Form**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="phone" >
        <option></option>
        <option value="samsung" <?php if($_POST["phone"]=="samsung")echo "selected"; ?>>Samsung</option>
        <option value="sony" <?php if($_POST["phone"]=="sony")echo "selected"; ?>>Sony</option>
    </select>

    <select name="issue" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option></option>
        <option value="screen" <?php if($_POST["issue"]=="screen")echo "selected"; ?> >Screen</option>
            <option value="battery" <?php if($_POST["issue"]=="battery")echo "selected"; ?>>Battery</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

What this **sample code** do: As soon as the user select an issue, it will `trigger` **OnChange()** event and `submit()` the form to the same page. The php code inside `<option>` tag is used to maintain the selected option after form is submitted.

3. **JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var price = <?php echo $price ?>;
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = price;
</script>
```

What this **sample code** do: You can pass PHP variable to JavaScript by using `echo`. Then, set  innerHTML to price.

To understand it better, the order of the event is **2**, **1**, **3**.

- **First**: user select an option from **HTML** form.
- **Second**, form submit, will check the **PHP** on top of your code.
- **Last**, **JavaScript** will change your Price label to the value you want.

Note: This is just a **sample**, hope it gives you an idea how to achieve this, let me know if this is what you wanted.

To achieve this with AJAX, use this method:

this is how your `form.php` should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Select with AJAX</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <select name="phone" id="phone">
        <option value="">Select device</option>
        <option value="iPhone 8">iPhone 8</option>
        <option value="iPhone XS">iPhone XS</option>
    </select>
    <select name="issue" id="issue">
        <option value="">Select issue</option>
        <option value="Battery">Battery</option>
        <option value="Water Damage">Water Damage</option>
    </select>

    <!-- DIV to show the Price-->
    <div id="price"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myAjaxCall (dataString){
            $.ajax({ 
              type: "POST", 
              url: "get-data.php", 
              data: dataString, 
              success: function(result){ 
                $("#price").html(result); 
              }
            });
        }

      $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $("#issue, #phone").change(function(event){ /* WHEN YOU CHANGE/SELECT ISSUE OR PHONE */
            //Phone select changed
            if ($(event.target).attr('id') == 'phone'){
                // alert('phone changed');
                var phone = $(this).val();
                var issue = document.getElementById('issue').value;
            }
            //Issue select changed
            else if ($(event.target).attr('id') == 'issue'){
                // alert ('issue changed');
                var issue= $(this).val(); 
                var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
            } 
            var dataString = "issue="+issue+"&phone="+phone; 
            myAjaxCall(dataString);
        });
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is how your `get-data.php` should look like:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["phone"]) && !empty($_POST["issue"])){
  /* DO YOUR QUERY HERE AND GET THE OUTPUT YOU WANT */
  
  if ($_POST['phone'] == 'iPhone 8' && $_POST['issue'] == 'Battery'){
    $price = 5;
  }
  else if ($_POST['phone'] == 'iPhone 8' && $_POST['issue'] == 'Water Damage'){
    $price = 28;
  }
  else if ($_POST['phone'] == 'iPhone XS' && $_POST['issue'] == 'Water Damage'){
    $price = 10;
  }
  else if ($_POST['phone'] == 'iPhone XS' && $_POST['issue'] == 'Battery'){
    $price = 25;
  }
  else $price = "";

  echo $price;
}
else echo "";
?>
```

Refer to this answer: [Do php query on select change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389767/how-do-i-execute-a-php-query-on-select-option-choice-using-ajax/32390447).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I was trying to implement this for days but I failed.

How do I solve the problem that the page needs to reload in order to show the price? Do I need to use AJAX?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. So do you expect the price to show without reload action? If that's what you mean, then I think you should use AJAX. It allows you to change content dynamically without the need to reload entire page. Can you update your new problem to let us know your current progress and where you get stuck? Cheers!

Comment: Hey, I am trying but I am really stuck with this whole thing.

So here is what I want to do: The user is able to select a phone and to select the issue within 2 select tags.
If I selected iPhone 8 and Water Damage it is supposed to immediately make the SQL Query and then print the price to repair the phone. This sounds so simple but I never have done anything with AJAX and I am struggling to find a good tutorial that shows me how to achieve this.

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, and what's the problem you are facing now? I know you are trying, I'm also trying to help but I have to know your current progress and where you are stuck now. The method that I gave requires the form to be submitted, hence, with a reload/refresh action, is this what you want to prevent? The reload action?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent the reload action. I am not getting firther than reading and not understanding AJAX Tutorials and using your code as my base.

Comment: `isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone']!=""` should be replaced with the equivalent: `!empty($_POST['phone'])`.  No one should be using your `query()` call because it is insecure/unstable.  We should only see a prepared statement here.  `$_POST` should be used when "writing to the server", `$_GET` should be used when "reading from the server". @Vite I recommend that you not copy this answer's code into your project.  Keep researching.

Comment: [@mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) Hey mick, thanks for the input, I really appreciate it! It was just a sample to show how everything works together. I suppose the problem here isn't the query, but rather how select with onchange can get php query result?

Comment: @NcXNaV I really appreciate your help. I checked the link from the other issue you gave me and I tried to solve this problem for a long time now but it still wont work. The code you use is from 2015, maybe that's the problem? I fixed the small issues you had in your code (#allbooks, &phone), I tried not to do a query but to just echo a set variable in order to make it simpler to test, but even that fails. I don't get this working since weeks.

Comment: @Vite Hello Vite, I've noticed a wrong `(` symbol, it was using chinese input. `&phone` is correct because it's passing multiple post value to `get-data.php`. I've further edit the code so you can directly copy main form as `form.php`, and the other as `get-data.php`.

Comment: Hey @NcXNaV, yes I got it working. Thank you so much for your help!
Now the problem is, that if you change the phone after you have already selected a phone and the issue, it wont update, since it only updates after the issue is selected. Do you know how this behaviour can be fixed? Do I need to update after every selection made?

Comment: Hello Vite. Yes you can add another event handler for `phone` as well, with a condition: check if `issue` has been selected. If `issue` has been selected, call same ajax, do the query, **else** simply `return false`.

Comment: I've added `OnChange` event handler for `phone` as well. Let me know if this is what you meant.